# Have a div fill the remaining space left from a div with a variable height

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx, styled-components

I would like to wrap each element without leaving any space left from a previous `div`. Each `div` has a variable height and I would like the elements to stack on top of each other.

```html
<div className="Notes-Grid" id='Notes-Grid'>
  <Note data={ "Create a new Post"} />
  <Note data={ "Oh acceptance apartments up sympathize astonished delightful. 
                 Waiting him new     lasting towards. Continuing melancholy especially so to. 
                 Me unpleasing impossible in attachment announcing so astonished. What ask leaf may 
                 nor upon door. Tended remain my do stairs. Oh smiling amiable am so visited cordial in                          offices hearted."} />
  <Note data={ "Test"} />
  <Note data={ "Testing 1233"} />
  <Note data={ "Test"} />
  <Note data={
    "Oh acceptance apartments up sympathize astonished delightful. Waiting him new lasting towards. Continuing melancholy especially so to. Me unpleasing impossible in attachment announcing so astonished. What ask leaf may nor upon door. Tended remain my do stairs. Oh smiling amiable am so visited cordial in offices hearted."} />
</div>
```

```css
.Notes-Grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Note {
  background-color: var(--dark_gray);
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

Output:

[image]

What I am trying to recreate:

[image]

If this can't be done using `flexbox` I am open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Use masonry (https://masonry.desandro.com/) for this layout. If it needs to be done through css only use columns.

```
.notes-grid {
 column-count:3;
  column-gap: 15px;
 
}

.note {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two ways to go about this:

1. Non-straight bottom edge of the `.Notes-Grid` box: Place each div in the columns right after the other, and let them just take the space they need
2. Straight bottom edge of the `.Notes-Grid` box: Make all three columns the same height, and let the divs inside grow - this will *result in some divs taking in more space than they would need*

There really is no other way around: Either have straight line, but the cells are growing, or have non-straight line, with original size of the cells being maintained.

### Implementation

For both options, you need `.Note-Column` divs for each column (in this case 3). They need to be siblings to each other and contain the given grid cell divs, which we will give a classname of `.Note-Cell`. Then, let `.Notes-Grid` be `display: flex`, and `flex-direction: row`. The `.Note-Column`'s need `flex: 1 1 0` now, so that they grow and shrink accordingly.

With this, you will have equal width columns, and the cells in the columns should be placed one after the other. Option #1 should be implemented by now.

For Option #2, you simply also set `display: flex` on the `.Note-Column`'s, and give `.Note-Cell`'s `flex: 1 1 0`. Also include a `justify-content: space-between` on the `.Note-Column`'s, in order to place the first and last cell on the border of `.Note-Grid`, which will achieve the mentioned straight bottom edge.

Voilá, now your Note-Grid should be working like you expect.

### Flexboxes

If you are confused by the flex commands used, take a look at [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I think flexboxes are explained quite well there.

Comment: Would this not make it difficult to make the whole section responsive?

Comment: That would be based on what you define as responsive. Do you want the columns to wrap? Or to make everything smaller? Both should not be a problem, but if you come up with a situation where this solution hinders Responsiveness, I could try to solve it.